# Content-Type header value missing when moving host

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I have downloaded and used a `DataServiceProvider` example, very basic and common "hello world"( the one with `Product` and `Category` Entities). I'm working with the newest `Microsoft.Data.Services` package.

I've built a client to work against it and it works. the `GET` request returns a `Category` and I edit it and call `SaveChanges()` to update.

When I decided to move the code from "hello world" virtual environment to my existing large application on IIS, the update stopped working. I'm talking about the same code - client and server!

`GET` works fine, but the `SaveChanges()` response throws an exeption:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code /><m:message xml:lang="en-US">Content-Type header value missing.</m:message></m:error>
```

though I can clearly see in fiddler that I did send a `Content-Type` header:
`"Content-Type: application/atom+xml"`

```
var sessionedUri = new Uri("http://myapp/odata.svc/", UriKind.Absolute);
        _oDataContext = new DemoService(sessionedUri);

        _oDataContext.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
        Category cate = _oDataContext.CreateQuery<Category>("Categories").FirstOrDefault();

        _oDataContext = new DemoService(sessionedUri);
        cate.Name = "somethin";
        _oDataContext.AttachTo("Categories", cate);
        _oDataContext.UpdateObject(cate);
        _oDataContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Were there any redirects (e.g. HTTP/302) during the POST? Can you share the SAZ file from Fiddler?

Comment: On my application on IIS there is a redirection by httphandler.

Comment: Disabling it solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the remark above:

Httphandlers intervene in the communication and may remove the header although I sent it.
Thanks Eric